# Getting 'Expected undefined to be false' in protractor Jasmine

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I am verifying whether one of the element must not be displayed.

The code is as below:

spec file:

```
expect(usersPage.isCreateTabDisplayed()).toBe(false);
```

usersPage definition for the method:

```
this.isCreateTabDisplayed = function()
    {
        waitUtil.isElementVisible(usersTab,repo.configData.configuration.longWaitTime);
        createUserTab.isPresent()
            .then( function(displayed) {
                console.log("create user tab  : "+ displayed);
                return displayed;
            });
    }
```

The element definition is as below:

```
<li ng-class="{active: (subview == 'add')}" ng-show="iSU || dp.ua" class="ng-hide"><a href="#/setup/users/all/add/" class="ng-binding">Create user</a></li>
```

When I run the code, i am getting "Expected undefined to be false" error message.

The console log displayed as "create user tab  : false" but why i am getting the error message and how to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have `then` sequences and `return`.

```
this.isCreateTabDisplayed = function()
    {
        return waitUtil.isElementVisible(usersTab,repo.configData.configuration.longWaitTime).then(() => {
            return createUserTab.isPresent().then( function(displayed) { // or you can just "return createUserTab.isPresent()"
                console.log("create user tab  : "+ displayed);
                return displayed;
            });
        });
    }
```

Also, you have protractor tag in your question, so why you dont use it?
Your code should looks something like this:

`expect(usersPage.getCreateTab().isDisplayed()).toBe(false);`

```
getCreateTab(): ElementFinder {
    browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(usersTab), repo.configData.configuration.longWaitTime).then(() => {
        return createUserTab; // or put there locator to "element" (find) createUserTab
    });
}
```

If I miss something, please note me in the comment.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your time, it worked. I used the below format,      `this.isCreateTabDisplayed = function()
    {
     return browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(usersTab), parseInt(repo.configData.configuration.mediumWaitTime))
         .then(() => { return createUserTab.isPresent(); });
    }`